# Python: How to identify socket from which data is received?

Tags: python, sockets

**Situation:** A server receives connecting clients, and waits for them to make requests.

**The Problem:** When clients connect, the socket created for them by the server is assigned the variable *clientsocket*. When a client makes a request, they are removed from a list of clients in the lobby. However, if two clients connect but don't make requests, the last client to connect becomes the variable *clientsocket*.

**Effect of Problem:** If the first client that connected decides to make a request, the variable clientsocket is removed from the lobby list. However, clientsocket will not be referring to the first client, but the second (Or last one to connect). So when the second makes a request, an error is generated saying that clientsocket cannot be removed from the lobby because it no longer exists in the lobby list. Meanwhile, client 1 still does.

Here is the snippet of code that does what I am talking about:

```
rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select([Listeningsocket]+ Connection_List,[],[])
    for i in rlist:
        if i == Listeningsocket:
            clientsocket,address = Listeningsocket.accept()
            Connection_List.append(clientsocket)

            continue
        else:
            try:
                data = i.recv(512)
            except IOError:
                data = ""
            if data:
                clientsocket = # <--- UPDATE CLIENT WITH CORRECT SOCKET
                Request_Type = str(data.decode())
```

As you can see, what I need to do is make sure that when I receive data, the clientsocket that sent the data becomes the variable clientsocket, and not the last one that connected.

data = i.recv(512)  but is there any way to determine what socket sent this?

Tried googling, but I don't think anyone has this problem. I hope that this isn't TOO specific. I'm sure someone else may want to determine the socket that sent the data too.

Comment: Does anyone think that making clientsocket = i in i.recv(512) would be a solution?

Comment: Yes, I shortened my code to clientsocket = i already. Thank you for your answer though. (It lends confidence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the globally visible `clientsocket` over and over is an accident waiting to happen. You should just change your code to use `i` - that's a socket too.

> data = i.recv(512) but is there any way to determine what socket sent
>   this

Like I said, `i` is that socket.

Comment: Are you saying I should refer to the client as i whenever I am doing anything with a socket sending data? Could you perhaps elaborate on how clientsocket will be an accident waiting to happen? I know the variable will be overwritten often with another socket depending on how fast request are made, but does it pose a risk of accidentally not changing or something?

Comment: @Xeon If your code is single-threaded, then indeed everything might work. But there's no need to overuse a global variable, just use `i` and pass it as argument.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to see if I can do that.

Comment: @cnicutar Why do you assume that `clientsocket` is global? This might be just a piece of a function (and it should be).

Comment: @freakish Even if it isn't global (which I still think it is) it is overused: the OP should use `i` directly.

Comment: @cnicutar In that case `i` is global as well. That's not really an issue at all.